# Javascript get values from multidimensional array object by other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a structure like below;

```
var devices = {
    'device-1' : {
      'id' :'device1',
      'template' :'template-1',
      'user-1' :{
        'name' : 'John Doe',
        'authority' : 'author1',
      },
      'admin-1' :{
        'name' : 'Bob Doe',
        'authority' : 'author2',
      },
      'user-35' :{
        'name' : 'Bill Doe',
        'authority' : 'author1',
      },
      'author-42' :{
        'name' : 'Jack Doe',
        'authority' : 'author1|author3',
      }
  },
    'device-2' : {
      'id' :'device2',
      'template' :'template-2',
      'some-27' :{
        'name' : 'John Doe',
        'authority' : 'author1',
      },
      'other-42' :{
        'name' : 'Jack Doe',
        'authority' : 'author2',
      }
  },
    'device-7' : {
      'id' :'device7',
      'template' :'template-1',
      'user-2' :{
        'name' : 'Samantha Doe',
        'authority' : 'author2',
      }
      'admin-40' :{
        'name' : 'Marry Doe',
        'authority' : 'author1',
      },
    }

};
```

and I would like to get all 'value' entries of user-x elements by filtering their 'property' values.

Eg.

I would like filter all 'name's of users (no matter in which device and what are those user-ids) based on their 'authority' property and get `'John Doe','Bill Doe','Jack Doe','Marry Doe'` (as an array) if I would like filter for 'author1' 'authority' so I can get which users have 'author1' authorities on any devices.

I've checked many places (including StackOverflow) but most of the examples are limited to two-dimensional object arrays, variables were specific or objects were based on an integer (like [0] => Array).

But in this example, `'device-x'` and `'user-x'` entries are uncertain (so I cannot say their values are these) but `'name'` and `'authority'` keys are certain (assign by the system) and the count of these variables can be varied (crud operations).

Thanks right now.

**UPDATE** : Because of my assumption error (I thought that if I write user-x parts different that each other, people think that these values are not follow any rule) question was not clear. So I edited in code.
Finally : owners of 'name' and 'authority' key-value pairs are user names and they are user defined.

So, all device objects will have id, template, unknown-user-field, but all unknown-user-fields must have 'name' and 'authority' key-value pairs.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: I am trying to use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes but couldn't succeed yet.
Because, while referenced QA is based on two-dimensional array, I couldn't implement to sub variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` & `filter` & `map`.

**Updated**: I've added a `isLikeUserObj` function that probs for `name` & `authority` fields.

```js
const devices = {
  'device-1': {
    'id': 'device1',
    'template': 'template-1',
    'user-1': {
      'name': 'John Doe',
      'authority': 'author1',
    },
    'admin-1': {
      'name': 'Bob Doe',
      'authority': 'author2',
    },
    'user-35': {
      'name': 'Bill Doe',
      'authority': 'author1',
    },
    'author-42': {
      'name': 'Jack Doe',
      'authority': 'author1|author3',
    }
  },
  'device-2': {
    'id': 'device2',
    'template': 'template-2',
    'some-27': {
      'name': 'John Doe',
      'authority': 'author1',
    },
    'other-42': {
      'name': 'Jack Doe',
      'authority': 'author2',
    }
  },
  'device-7': {
    'id': 'device7',
    'template': 'template-1',
    'user-2': {
      'name': 'Samantha Doe',
      'authority': 'author2',
    },
    'admin-40': {
      'name': 'Marry Doe',
      'authority': 'author1',
    },
  }
};

const result = getUserByAuthority('author3');

function getUserByAuthority(requiredAuth) {
  return Object.keys(devices).reduce((result, deviceKey) => {
    const users = Object.keys(devices[deviceKey])
      .filter((key) => isUserLikeObj(devices[deviceKey][key]))
      .map(userKey => devices[deviceKey][userKey])
      .filter((user) => user.authority.split('|').indexOf(requiredAuth) > -1)
      .map((user) => user.name)
    return result.concat(users);
  }, [])
}

function isUserLikeObj(value) {
  return typeof value === 'object' && value.hasOwnProperty('name') && value.hasOwnProperty('authority')
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please can you check question update

Comment: Are device object gonna contain `id`, `template`, `unknown-user-field`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But all unknown-user-fields must have 'name' and 'authority' key-value pairs.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use for-in loop to traverse an object. Following ways could achieve your need

```
const result = []

for (let i in devices) {
  for (let j in devices[i]) {
    if (/user-\d+/.test(j)) {
      if (devices[i][j].authority.split('|').indexOf('author1') !== -1) {
        result.push(devices[i][j].name)
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please can you check question update